# Set flag when linked server unreachable, oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to set a flag in my database in case a linked server, from which I periodically update my data, is unreachable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you using Oracle Replication or Streams?  Oracle hese sortprovides these built-in features which handle ts of things for us, precisely so we don't have to roll our own.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select from dual at the remote database and note when it's not available.

```
declare

   l_available number;

begin

   begin

      -- Try and find the remote DB.
      execute immediate 'select 1 from dual@remote_db'
                    into l_available;

   exception when others then
      l_available := 0;

   end;

   update my_table
      set available = l_available
    where server = remove_db;

end;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much but the query on the linked server takes a lot of time and the connection could go down during the query.

I guess i could use the actual query instead of the select 1 in the same way

Comment: Yes, or if the query errors then run this to double check whether the query failed or the server did.